# How to only apply str.split in Python on certain Rows or conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I've been doing webscraping in Python and hit a problem which broke my script.  I usually separate a certain column with `str.split()` on `-`, which gives me the columns I want and normally just populates everything I don't need with NA (which is fine).

Today I hit an edge case where a player with a hyphen popped up which made this not work.  Below is a reproducible example, the data usually has 500+ rows so this instance could occur multiple times.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"score": ["Jump ball: Shai-Gilgeous Alexander vs Jeremiah Robinson-Earl", "0-0"]})

# this doesnt work anymore because of 2 players with a hyphen popped up,
# which makes this return more than the 2 columns i want

df[["scoreAway", "scoreHome"]] = df["score"].str.split(
    "-", expand=True
)
```

error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

The solution to me is I need to replace hyphens with spaces, but only on rows that have that score = str.contains("Jump ball:").  So `Shai-Gilgeous Alexander` would become `Shai Gilgeous Alexander`, and the 0-0 would remain unaffected.  But I'm having a hard time finding resources on how to do that.

If anyone has a quick fix or suggestion I'd appreciate it!

Comment: It's working for me. Run this code to see what I'm getting: `print("                                           score        scoreAway                      scoreHome\n0  Jump ball: Shai-Gilgeous Alexander vs player1  Jump ball: Shai  Gilgeous Alexander vs player1\n1                                            0-0                0                              0")`

Comment: My bad, updated the example.  had a typo & forgot to include the second hyphenated player which is what's causing the issue.

Comment: Aha. With your latest edit I'm getting the issue. Let's see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `n=1` to the `.str.split()` call:

```py
df[["scoreAway", "scoreHome"]] = df["score"].str.split(
    "-", expand=True, n=1
)
```

That will cause it to split on the first `-` only.

Comment: Actually, use rsplit in this example with n=1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html